# SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; Does the "Time" column reset between states for the same query?

Tags: mysql

Taken directly from the documentation:

> - Time
>
> The time in seconds that the thread has been in its current state.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html

*(Linking version 5.7 docs as it is the version my question currently pertains to, however the latest version of the MySQL docs have the exact same verbiage surrounding this column.)*

The last of that sentence is what I have been paying close attention to lately "in its current state". So, if I take this literally, I would expect the time value for a single process, to reset back to 0 as the (same) query moves forward along its different states.

Is this assumption correct? Searching around doesn't yield much info on this particular question...

A recent issue I had a situation where there were many open processes with a State value of `Waiting for table level lock`, all on the same table. Reviewing the process list, looking for what currently running process would have held the lock on the table at that time, I encountered a query with a state of `Sending data`. This process had a "Time" value of over 2 hours, and I am unsure if it has been in that state of "Sending data" for two hours, or if this is the total time for *that query of that process*. For example, if earlier this query had also been in a state of "Waiting for table level lock", is that part of the very high value it currently has for "Time".

Comment: For my experience, the time doesn't change between status of the queries. Maybe they only change between some status, but, between processing query and sending data at least, doesn't change.

Comment: I believe you are correct @SakuraKinomoto. After re-reading my own question today, it just occurred to me the documentation states "thread", not "query". I believe this is a clear indicator here I did not lean on before. I did not have time to create a scenario to prove this, however if you were to want to post it as your answer I'd accept it.